# How to filter two Dictionaries with multiple keys Swift 4?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, filter

I have two Dictionaries.

```
[
["price": 65,   "sku": abcd], 
["price": 130,  "sku": efgh], 
["price": 195,  "sku": ijkl],
["price": 325,  "sku": mnop]
]
```

And:

```
[
["productId": abcd, "price": 79],
["productId": wxyz, "price": 79], 
["productId": opki,"price": 159], 
["productId": efgh, "price": 249],
["productId": ijkl, "price": 249], 
["productId": ytui, "price": 299], 
["productId": mnop, "price": 399] 
]
```

I  want to match the `sku` and `productId`.

How can I filter these two Dictionaries? I have tried the filter method but it gives a lot of error. I do not think for loop is a good idea for this kind of filtering. Can anyone help me? These two are the type of: `Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>`.

Edit: What I tried.

`self.filteredArr = arr1?.filter{ $0["productId"] as! String == arr2![0]["sku"] as! String}`

But, it throws multiple errors and I do not know if it is the right way to filter.

Comment: Can you share the code you tried?

Comment: Also, the dictionaries don't seem valid, should the `sku`/`productId` values be quoted?

Comment: @Cristik Added what I have tried. And, the dictionaries are valid. One of them is coming from Apple's side.

Comment: I was referring to the values like `abcd`? Shouldn't they be quoted, like `"abcd"`?

Comment: They are quoted from server side, but not from Apple side.

Comment: @Cristik I have added a new solution which is kind of working, but how can make it dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
let filteredArray = array2.filter { dic2 in

    array1.contains(where: { dic1 in 
        dic1["sku"] as! String == dic2["productId"] as! String 
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is a2 in here, like `for a2 in 0...9` ?

Comment: a2 is just a variable which is nothing but the dictionary in array2. Wait I will modify the answer so you have a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.